# Текст в моём приложении Xamarin исчезает на One S Plus

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Сделал приложение на Xamarin. Вот так оно выглядит в Дебагере и на моём телефоне:

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTHE.jpg)

У друга One S Plus (Android 10 ) и он присылает, что у него приложение выглядит вот так:

[my app screen of One S Plus with bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phpdF.jpg)

Почему-то все Label стали невидимыми или пропали. Проверили на Honor 10 (Android 9), Samsung A71 - на них всё нормально. У меня есть подозрения, что проблема не только на One S Plus. Почему такое могло произойти, что можно сделать? Целевая платформа в настройках приложения - Android 10

Код разметки:

```
   <ScrollView x:Name="scroll1" Grid.Row="1" >
        <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayout1" Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="Детали Вашего мероприятия:" FontSize="Title"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />                
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />                  
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Image Source="time.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
                <Label Text="Сколько планируем отдыхать?" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="0,10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
           
            </Grid>
        
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Picker x:Name="picker" SelectedIndexChanged="picker_SelectedIndexChanged" Title="Основательно, до ночи" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
                <Picker.Items>
                    <x:String>На пару-тройку часиков</x:String>
                    <x:String>Основательно, до ночи</x:String>
                    <x:String>До утреннего крика петухов</x:String>                    
                </Picker.Items>
                    
            </Picker>
                <Image Source="ic_arrow_drop_down.png"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="drop_down" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>                    
                
            </Grid>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="fork.png"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />

                <Label Text="Какое мясо будем кушать?" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="16" Padding="0,4,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" IsVisible="True"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="Svinina"  BackgroundColor="White" IsVisible="True" >

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />                     
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="#EBEBEB"  />
                
                
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Margin="2">
                    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="5" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Source="svinina.png"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalOptions="Fill" />


                        <Label Text="Свинина" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="20" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" IsVisible="True" />
                        <Image Source="cancel.png" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Fill" >
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="delete_svinina" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>

                        </Image>

                    </Grid>

                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="1">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "Auto" />
                        
                        
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                        <Label Text="Количество персон:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="16" Padding="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,-15"/>


                        <Label Text="Дамы:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Label Text="Господа:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                        <Label Text="Дети:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>

                        <Entry Placeholder="" x:Name="EntryText1" Unfocused="OnEntryTextUnFocused1" Focused="OnEntryTextFocused1" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="0 чел." Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Entry Placeholder="" x:Name="EntryText2" Unfocused="OnEntryTextUnFocused2" Focused="OnEntryTextFocused2"  Keyboard="Numeric" Text="0 чел." Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Entry Placeholder="" x:Name="EntryText3" Unfocused="OnEntryTextUnFocused3" Focused="OnEntryTextFocused3" Keyboard="Numeric" Text="0 чел." Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="17" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
                        <Stepper Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Minimum="-1000" Maximum="1000" Increment="1" ValueChanged="OnStepperValueChanged1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="0,8,0,0" />
                        
                      
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,-40,0,0">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width= "0,3*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Switch x:Name="Switch1" Toggled="OnToggled1" IsToggled="false" Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
                       
                        <Label Text="Кто-то хочет разнообразия" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="16" Padding="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextType="Text" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" Margin="-10,0,0,0"/>

                    </Grid>
```

Comment: `Почему такое могло произойти, что можно сделать?` - вангую, что вы весь интерфейс рисовали в редакторе, а не писали сами, а редактор вам подобавлял всяких `Margin="999, 100, 5, 10"`. Ну а так, вы говорите про баг кода, а код нам не даете, хотите чтоб мы ванговали?

Comment: Вставьте код разметки страницы в вопрос

Comment: @aepot , код разметки вставил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ код разметки вставил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста. Насчёт рисования в редакторе, я так понимаю у Xamarin.Forms нет редактора, я бы с удовольствием там рисовал.

Comment: Вопрос про все надписи, или про какие-то конкретные?

Comment: Не знаю хамарин, но если бы это было обычное андроид-приложение, я бы шапку поставил на то, что проблема в теме (стиле). Тёмный стиль сейчас модно, поэтому наверняка у друга это основной стиль системы. Вы же принудительно задаёте белый фон своим `Grid`-ам и поэтому текст сливается с фоном (у тёмного стиля, естественно, цвет текста - белый).

Comment: @aepot , вообще никакие label не показываются.. только картинки и элементы управления

Comment: @woesss Действительно в этом и проблема была! Спасибо большое. Для всех label просто добавил чёрный цвет текста и для моего белого фона теперь показывается на обеих темах.